# Gerrit authentication with Gitlab

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid, gitlab, gerrit

I've been at various tutorials using gitHub (plugin) for Gerrit authentication. However, I would wish to use gitlab as an authentication provider for gerrit. I've searched internet but nothing meaningful was found. Does somebody know of any tutorial that would help me do the same.

Comment: AFAIK GL can't be currently used as an auth provider out of the box. This is partly because it focuses on local installs instead of the SaaS, where providing auth is generally less useful. Are you running both locally? If Gerrit supports LDAP auth, you could use that for both GL and Gerrit (requires GL EE, which is cheap).

Comment: Yes, both are hosted locally. Sorry for asking, but I am still not very clear on how to integrate both using LDAP. AFAIK, LDAP configuration into Gerrit config should be fine, but not sure if that's all which I need. GitLab is properly setup ob a local instance.

Comment: I personally have never touched LDAP so I may be wrong, but IIUC you want to have a single login for both is that so? In that case you might be able to use LDAP as a single login method for both.

Comment: Actually, I just verified my .yml file, and found out that we are not using ldap or openid for authentication. In that scenario, having a common credential base/single login becomes difficult.

Answer (score 0):

We use a separate ldap server for authentication in gitlab.

The same ldap server is used for gerrit.

I do not see a way how gitlab would provide an authentication mechanism for other services.

Comment: I've seen that gitHub does provide OAuth authentication for other services, hence on the similar lines, gitlab should (may be in future) provide mechanism to authenticate "related" services. However, the issue at hand is, we are not using LDAP/OpenId to authenticate GitLab, hence I don't see a machanism how I can avoid migration of credentials from GitLab to Gerrit.